# ASUS ZenBook - Battery is never fully charged

Tags: power-management, laptop, acpi, battery, asus

I have installed Linux Mint 18.2 Cinnamon (kernel: 4.10.0-32-generic) on my new ASUS UX430UA notebook. However, described behavioral was also found on **other ZenBooks** and other used OSes like Linux Mint 18.2 Xfce, Linux Mint 18.2 KDE, recent KDE Neon, Peppermint OS 8, Xubuntu 16.04, Kubuntu 16.04 and Ubuntu 16.04 however. Also tried Ubuntu 14.04, but I failed with installing.

The power indicator (bottom bar) never shows that notebook battery is fully charged (as well as upower), it shows discharging instead. However it is not discharging at all, because battery has still the same energy level. So it must be also charging at one time.

Charging works just like it should as well as state of battery while charging. It charges to full battery and then until battery energy falls to 90% or below, it doesn't charge it.

Most of system events regarding to battery state behave just like battery state is interpreted (dimming screen when AC is plugged in when battery has 90% of its energy or above, maybe my notebook is nearly continuously running in a power save mode (what I don't want to) and others).

**What I tried:**

- Change OS (only Linux distros, Windows 10 was fine with this issue) - KDE based distributions icons of battery and system events work well, but battery state in upower was the same as described later
- update BIOS (I have the most recent version of BIOS installed - v300)
- edit image of the most recent BIOS (failed with this editing)
- calibration battery by drain all the energy and recharge again
- add to GRUB the following parameters: "acpi_osi=Linux" and "acpi_backlight=vendor" and also others
- edit my current DSDT table, but unsuccessfully - I failed with recompiling kernel in generated DSDT.hex file
- write to ASUS to check their BIOS (it looks that they don't want to help me so much, because I am using Linux, which is not supported on this device)

**Where I think the problem is:**

I think that problem could be in bad DSDT delivered by ASUS in BIOS. User shutt1e is also describing the possible solution to the same problem in answer for [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/587063/battery-indicator-always-says-using-battery-power-even-when-plugged-in-asus) question.

**`upower -d`** when AC power connected:

```
Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/line_power_AC0
  native-path:          AC0
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Thu 27 Jul 2017 11:21:30 PM CEST (40 seconds ago)
  has history:          no
  has statistics:       no
  line-power
    warning-level:       none
    online:              yes
    icon-name:          'ac-adapter-symbolic'

Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
  native-path:          BAT0
  vendor:               ASUSTeK
  model:                ASUS Battery
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Thu 27 Jul 2017 11:21:30 PM CEST (40 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               discharging
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              47,412 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         50,069 Wh
    energy-full-design:  50,069 Wh
    energy-rate:         7,114 W
    voltage:             11,55 V
    time to empty:       6,7 hours
    percentage:          94%
    capacity:            100%
    technology:          lithium-ion
    icon-name:          'battery-full-symbolic'
  History (rate):
    1501190490  7,114   discharging
    1501190488  4,735   discharging

Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/DisplayDevice
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Thu 27 Jul 2017 11:21:30 PM CEST (40 seconds ago)
  has history:          no
  has statistics:       no
  battery
    present:             yes
    state:               discharging
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              47,412 Wh
    energy-full:         50,069 Wh
    energy-rate:         7,114 W
    time to empty:       6,7 hours
    percentage:          94%
    icon-name:          'battery-full-symbolic'

Daemon:
  daemon-version:  0.99.4
  on-battery:      no
  lid-is-closed:   no
  lid-is-present:  yes
  critical-action: HybridSleep
```

**`upower -d`** when AC power disconnected:

```
Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/line_power_AC0
  native-path:          AC0
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Thu 27 Jul 2017 11:24:36 PM CEST (4 seconds ago)
  has history:          no
  has statistics:       no
  line-power
    warning-level:       none
    online:              no
    icon-name:          'ac-adapter-symbolic'

Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
  native-path:          BAT0
  vendor:               ASUSTeK
  model:                ASUS Battery
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Thu 27 Jul 2017 11:24:36 PM CEST (4 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               discharging
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              47,401 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         50,069 Wh
    energy-full-design:  50,069 Wh
    energy-rate:         4,735 W
    voltage:             11,55 V
    time to empty:       10,0 hours
    percentage:          94%
    capacity:            100%
    technology:          lithium-ion
    icon-name:          'battery-full-symbolic'
  History (rate):
    1501190676  4,735   discharging
    1501190611  0,079   discharging

Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/DisplayDevice
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Thu 27 Jul 2017 11:24:36 PM CEST (4 seconds ago)
  has history:          no
  has statistics:       no
  battery
    present:             yes
    state:               discharging
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              47,401 Wh
    energy-full:         50,069 Wh
    energy-rate:         4,735 W
    time to empty:       10,0 hours
    percentage:          94%
    icon-name:          'battery-full-symbolic'

Daemon:
  daemon-version:  0.99.4
  on-battery:      yes
  lid-is-closed:   no
  lid-is-present:  yes
  critical-action: HybridSleep
```

When battery is correctly charged, its state should be "fully-charged" instead of "discharging" in prints above.

I am afraid of notebook battery life. Do you have any idea to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing same issue with Asus Zenbook UX430UQ with Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS 64 bit. My motherboard bios version was 300 released on 13/July/2017. Downgraded to older 201 firmware released on 10/Feb/2017. Now battery notification and charging beautifully.